# C++ Math with different types, when do I cast?

Tags: c++, types, casting, arduino

While writing a short program for my Arduino Pro Mini (ATMEGA328, 8MHz) I thought about a math part and I want to optimize it, but don't know which way is the best.

Since I'm working on 8bit without dedicated float math, and space(SRAM) is rare, I want to have as much in Integer-Math as possible (is this correct?)

Here is a part of my code, I have not included any casts now, to keep it clean.

```
//In the future they can change (that's why no "const")
uint8_t deadband = 2; 
uint8_t amp_fwd = 20;
uint8_t amp_break = 5;

int8_t throttle; //This is read from a potentiometer

if (throttle > deadband){
  OutputFWD(throttle * amp_fwd / 127);
} else if (throttle < -deadband) {
  OutputBREAK((throttle + 127) * amp_break / (127 - amp_break));
} else {
  OutputFWD(0);
  OutputBREAK(0);
}

void OutputFWD(float ampere){} // Only positive values
void OutputBREAK(float ampere){} // Only positive values
```

Some explanation:

It's is a control for a motor. It reads a value (throttle) from a potentiometer. Everything over mid throttle (0 to 127) drives the FWD output and everything below (-127 to 0) drives the breaks. I have included a deadband as you can see, so it won't swing between these two.

Looking at the *OutputBREAK* I had an idea. Would it be sufficient to make the "127" float/decimal (Write 127.0)? Or do I have to cast before every variable (that's what I did before...). Another idea was to change the definitions of my variables to *float*.

Thank you for your time and help with my casts.
Regards

Comment: You don't need to cast anything. If you want to turn any arithmetic operation with a literal value (like `127`) into a floating point operation, all you need to do is make the literal value a floating pointer value, like e.g. `127.0f`. The `.0` says that it's a floating point value, and the `f` suffix says that it's of type `float` (otherwise it defaults to `double`).

Comment: You absolutely should do the math in floating point (or at least larger integers), because you're likely to overflow the 8-bit value in your `OutputFWD` calculation.  PS: did you mean "brake" (as in 'slow down').  `break` is a reserved word in C++.

Comment: @paddy Yea it was "break". Thanks to point that out. Changed it.
I want to do it as efficient as possible (large int or float). I'm don't know how to optimize it. (Like i said i just wrote "(float)" infront of everything ^^)

Comment: Do you perhaps have a slightly bent view of efficiency?  Is this all your program is supposed to do?  It should be fine, but the biggest bottleneck will probably be floating-point emulation.  You could avoid that by rearranging your math in fixed point on a 16-bit integer and avoid float altogether.  If you don't mind dividing by 128 instead of 127 then you can use a right-shift of 7 bits instead.

Comment: @paddy i have no clue of efficiency in C++. No my program does a lot more so the space is rare. Could you write a short answer how to do this with 16-bit integer? Or link me somewhere? Then i would close it.

Comment: What are the reasons why you want to optimize this piece of code ? You'd be very surprised to see what 8MHz can achieve. I can assure you trying to optimize using int usually causes more harm than anything else because of overflows you'll get and the extra code you'll have to produce to prevent them.
Best would be to do the calculations using float and then clamp to ± 127 interval and store that value.

Comment: @AlexG The program does a lot more than this and it really is for educational purpose to do it myself in the future. What do you mean by "calculations in float and then >>clamp<< to ± 127" ? Can you give me a short example ?

Comment: Why don't you try writing a minimal example that performs a short calculation using only `uint16_t` and generate the assembly for it.  Then do it again for `float`.  Compare the actual instructions being used, and that will give you an idea of the efficiency.

Comment: 'Cause i have no board at hand. I'm not at home and instead of boring me to death here i'm writing some code (just in n++). But yea, i will figure it out somehow. Just thought someone would share his/her experience so i don't get "roasted" in the future when displaying code. But nvm.